# Will houri be available to people in Jannat?

Tags: sharia, women, islamic-basis, houri

Salam,

I have heard many times through many people that if one does follow all the necessary Islamic laws and happens to be placed in Jannat(heaven), then the man ***will receive hoor(Houri)*** (very beautiful human like creatures - angels) ***to serve him in Jannat***.

Is it true? Please answer with references.

If it is true, then ***what will women receive*** if they happen to be placed in Jannat?

Answer (score 1):

Proofs from Qur'an:

> So (it will be), and We shall marry them to Houris (female fair ones)
>   with wide, lovely eyes. (Ad-Dukhan 44:54)
>
> They will recline (with ease) on thrones arranged in ranks. And We
>   shall marry them to Houris (female, fair ones) with wide lovely eyes.
>   (At-Tur 52:20)
>
> Houris (beautiful, fair females) restrained in pavilions; (Ar-Rahman
>   55:72)
>
> And (there will be) Houris (fair females) with wide, lovely eyes (as
>   wives for the pious), (Al-Waqi'ah 56:22)

http://thenoblequran.com/sps/nbq/

Proofs from Hadith:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet said, "The first batch (of people)
>   who will enter Paradise will be (glittering) like the full moon, and
>   the batch next to them will be (glittering) like the most brilliant
>   star in the sky. Their hearts will be as if the heart of a single man,
>   for they will have neither enmity nor jealousy amongst themselves;
>   everyone will have two wives from the houris, (who will be so
>   beautiful, pure and transparent that) the marrow of the bones of their
>   legs will be seen through the bones and the flesh." [Al-Bukhari vol.4,
>   book 54, number 476]
>
> Narrated Anas (R.A.): The Prophet (صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم) said, "A single
>   endeavor (of fighting) in Allah's Cause in the afternoon or in the
>   forenoon is better than all the world and whatever is in it. A place
>   in Paradise as small as the bow or lash of one of you is better than
>   all the world and whatever is in it. And if a houri from Paradise
>   appeared to the people of the earth, she would fill the space between
>   Heaven and the Earth with light and pleasant scent and her head cover
>   is better than the world and whatever is in it." [Al-Bukhari volume 4,
>   book 52, number 53]

Righteous women will become the leader amongst the several houris which will be married to each righteous man.

Comment: so basically Men will get Hoors , but women wont , is it ??

Comment: My friend it is the way how you look at things...if a man gets a beautiful wife then it is obvious that the wife is getting a husband as well -:)

Comment: Why are you so worried what women will get when your a guy?

Comment: @MrJannah : because , females are humans as well , they deserve rights , one should have knowledge whether he is guy or a girl , I have never seen a stupider comment.